# What is the most efficient way to store csv data locally for use in c++ dll?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a 5MB csv file. My dll will go through this csv and process it into a map.

Now, my issue is whenever i restart my dll-calling program, the csv is downloaded again. Its very time consuming. I know I can store this csv locally. But even then i have to parse this csv to map everytime program is reloaded. My csv file is about 75000 rows. Is there a more efficient way to store this parsed data for ready use in dll.

Note: This csv needs to be downloaded every day since its updated daily.

Comment: You could serialize the map into a file and load that, if that's going to save you time spent in parsing.

Comment: C++ should have no performance problems with serializing a simple csv data structure into a map with only 75000 rows.

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered as it is. I mean it's unclear why the reading is taking long? Perhaps the parsing algorithm is slow? Or maybe its the data? What is considered slow here? Are we talking about a few seconds? A minute or more? Maybe we need to see some code and a better description of the data.

Comment: Overall, I would say that you should focus on optimizing your CSV parsing system (but only if it's actually a performance problem). It's very easy to write a parser that is exceedingly slow. If you're using IOStreams... stop that. If you're using `stoi` or similar things to do data conversion, those will be pretty slow. Don't copy strings from the CSV unless you absolutely have to. And so forth.

Comment: It also will likely be slow if you are using a debug build instead of release.